# Making a complicated image path from a cell/title in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with lots of rows containing a title. A title can look like this:

```
Title - Subtitle
```

I want to use that title to create an image path. Four things that needs to include the formula:

1. Because the sheet contains lots of rows, an **ARRAYFORMULA** would be ideal.
2. **Add a text/path before** the title. For example: `../img/`
3. grab the title, **convert in lowercase** (if possible) and **replace empty spaces with an underscore**. For example: `title_-_subtitle`
4. Last but not least I want to **add a text/extension afterwards**. For example: `.png`

The total output I want to achieve with a title like "Title - Subtitle" would be:

```
../img/title_-_subtitle.png
```

[image]

Any help/tip would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;SUBSTITUTE(LOWER("../img/"&B2:B&
 IF(C2:C="";;"_-_"&C2:C)&".png"); " "; "_"))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,SUBSTITUTE(LOWER("../img/"&B2:B&".png"), " ", "_")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again player0, much appreciated! Have a nice day

Comment: I'd like to add that references are always useful when it comes to new users in the community that see this kind of post. [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215).

Comment: @JoseVasquez https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=3105625